# Enabling buttons

Tags: iphone

Problem,

with a UIButton, I can do this:

```
myButton.enabled = YES;
       or 
myButton.enabled = NO;
```

However, I can't do the same with a UIBarButtonItem (navigation bar buttons,)

So, how do I stop the user clicking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can; a UIBarButtonItem is a subclass of UIBarItem, which has an enabled property. Just use that.

Just get a reference to the item and do what you have above:

```
UIBarButtonItem  *item = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;

item.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: how do i do that? i cant seem to figure it out... :S

Comment: huh. i tried that.

well it didnt work last night, but it works now. odd. 

Cheers Ben.